# ¿Cómo implementar el siguiente programa con múltiples datos como input?

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nuevo y no consigo que este programa se ejecute como quiero.

Necesito que se formulen las 5 preguntas y contabilice las respuestas correctas. El problema es que cada vez que ejecuto el código siempre se para en el primer `if` independientemente de la respuesta que se le de a la pregunta.

Muchas gracias.

```
var respuesta=0;


var quest=prompt("La tierra es plana? S/N");
if(quest==N || quest==n){
    respuesta++;

}
var quest2=prompt("El cielo es azul? S/N");
if(quest2==S || quest2==s){
    respuesta++;
 
}
var quest3=prompt("Un dia tiene 24 horas? S/N");
if(quest3==S || quest3==s){
    respuesta++;

}
var quest4=prompt("Un minuto tiene 60 segundos? S/N");
if(quest4==S || quest4==s){
    respuesta++;

}
var quest5=prompt("2+2=5? S/N");
if(quest5==N || quest5==n){
    respuesta++;
}
alert("Tienes "+respuesta+" correctas");
```

Comment: Las comparaciones con `string` deben ir entre comillas: `if(quest=='N' || quest=='n'){`

Comment: Ten en cuenta que los valores literales de texto deben encerrarse en comillas. De otro modo se interpretan como variables, y dichas variables no se han creado (S,s,N,n) y por ello el error. `N is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque lo que se captura del prompt es una cadena así que debe compararse como tal, entre comillas simples o dobles.

```js
var respuesta = 0;


var quest = prompt("La tierra es plana? S/N");
// la variable quest se compara contra cadenas 'N' 'n'
if(quest == 'N' || quest ==  'n'){
    respuesta++;
}


alert("Tienes "+respuesta+" correctas");
```

En lugar de comparar contra mayúsculas y minúsculas puedes usar la función `toLowerCase()` para convertir la entrada en minúsculas y hacer solo una comparación.

```js
var respuesta = 0;


var quest = prompt("La tierra es plana? S/N");

if(quest.toLowerCase() == 'n'){
    respuesta++;
}


alert("Tienes "+respuesta+" correctas");
```